# Joomla Content builder short codes appearing on webpage

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

My website has recently been attached by malware and i am trying to reinstate the website by doing a fresh install.
I have set up a localhost to ensure the installation is working well before migrating to my host server.
I have done all the necessary installations i can think of and currently running PHP v 5.6, mysql, and Joomla 3.5, sppagebuilder free v 1.3., shaper_qubic - Default as my template.
My set up displays my webpages alright but also with the sp bulder codes in the front end pages. This is not so cool and i have reinstalled and updated every plug in but the problem just doesnt go away. Here is a screen shot of what I am facing.
[image]

I have no idea what else to do and have exhausted all search materials for a solution.

My problem above led me to the SP Page builder section of joomla found another ugly look. 
[image]

Seems a query to SP_page builder hits a snag but i cant think far as to what could be the root cause and how to fix it. I thought my database could be the culprit so i checked the database section for joomla and it seems pretty okay as per the screen shot below.

[image]

I kindly look up to you awesome, helpful, big heart, gurus here to help me figure this out.

Thanks very much for all your inputs.

---

My sincere thanks to Amit and everyone extending a hand. I have followed your answer and here is some updates. Good thing, the error message on SP_pagebuilder page is gone. yay!... Not so good thing, i get a COM_SPPAGEBUILDER_ERROR_PAGE_NOT_FOUND when i open the website. :( 
I guess its important i mention that shaper_qubic - Default as my template.
How can i fix this please?
[image]

[image]

[image]

I did a littile snooping around and digging and found out that some addons that were installed on my webhost do not exist on my localhost. these addons were used to create content on the webhost and as a result, their absence is causing the same contents on the localhost not to show up well. How can I get the addons from my webhost to match that on my localhost without having to purchase nor reinstall them?
Here are some of the addons that I nicked: Contact Form, Animated NUmber, Audio, Block Number, Blockquote, Button Group, Call to Action, Clients, Drop Cap, Google Map, Image Content, Modal Popup, Person, Pie Progress, Pricing table, Progress bar, Raw HTML, Soundcloud.

Attached below is a screnshot of comparing addons on the localhost and webhost respectively.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going throught the extension I have found out some mistakes donein the extension. First when you uninstall a component it should uninstall completely but the uninstall file is empty. So even if you uninstall the old database will be there. So it wont update when you reinstall. If you look at the 1.0.7-2015-10-12.sql file in the admin/sql/updates you will find a line

```
ALTER TABLE `#__sppagebuilder` ADD `catid` int(10) NOT NULL AFTER `published`;
```

which means it was added later in version 1.0.7. You probably had an earlier version not having catid.

**SOLUTION:**

1. First DELETE the SP Pagebuilder tables
   You have to delete the 2 tables manually from phpmyadmin. The tables are
   `#__sppagebuilder` and `#__spmedia` (replace #_ with your table prefix. You can see other tables prefix in that database).
2. After deleting the two tables you have to install the tables again using this code. Run through SQL.

```html
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__sppagebuilder` (
      `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `alias` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `text` mediumtext NOT NULL,
      `published` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `catid` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `access` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `ordering` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `created_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      `created_user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `modified_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      `modified_user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `og_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `og_image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `og_description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `page_layout` varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
      `language` char(7) NOT NULL,
      `hits` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    
    
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__spmedia` (
      `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `path` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `thumb` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `alt` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `caption` varchar(2048) NOT NULL,
      `description` mediumtext NOT NULL,
      `type` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'image',
      `extension` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `created_on` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      `created_by` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `modified_on` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      `modified_by` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Replace #_ with your table prefix.
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Amit. Your answer was very elaborate and intuitive. I did just as you instructed and the error on SP_Page builder vanished. only issue now is that I get a 404 error when i lunch the website. I have edited my question with snapshots of the error and what the sp_pagebuilder looks like and database section too

Comment: @Selase if you are having htaccess.txt file then rename it to .htaccess. it will be in the root directory. Also to know exact error you can enable error to maximum in global configuration. you can also enable debug to get exact error if htaccess solution does not work.

Comment: Ah! hi there Amit. I got figured out something little and fixed the 404. i figured the table i replaced was lacking inserts so i run the insert query with the necessary data and now the page loads. I however have one of the issues mentioned occuring. that is the SP_Pagebuuilder codes showing up in the content on the website. do i have to run an insert for #_spmedia? cant find it in my backed up DB.sql file

Comment: there are no inserts for #__spmedia. Can you send me your url link?

Comment: Hi Amit, The link to the infected website is [link](http://gmaworld.com). I am currently running on localhost to set up before replacing the infected one online and its on the localhost that I'm facing the errors. I will be more than glad to share the details with you. do send me your email please. thanks.

Comment: Your infected site is opening fine. Which files got infected? You have to be careful using any third party extension. you can send your details to amit k ray @ gmail . com (remove spaces).

Comment: Hi Amit, I sent you an email. kindly check please. Thank you.

Comment: @Selase i will go through it.

Comment: Where are the recommended places to look and check if  addons are missing for joomla SP_PageBuilder? They existed and i used them to build content but they just disappeared for no apparent reason and the content that I used the missing addons to create do not turn up well because the addons are not there to format the content. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: @Selase you can get all the addons here https://www.joomshaper.com/page-builder/addons

Comment: Thanks very much. youve been very helpful and a life saver. I cant thank you enough. I followed the link and it seems I have to purchase the very same addons that I already have. However I found a work around. I was able to track down the folder in my root>components>com_sppagebuilder>addons once i copied all the contents of this folder into a similar path in my localhost, I was able to get the addons to show and subsequently the webpages appear without the codes in line. I'm in your debts for guiding me all the way till this far. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Selase Its my pleasure. Helping others I too learn a lot from the issues.